# SSL certificate installation on Apache server via FTP

Tags: ssl-certificate, ftp

I do have a `domain.crt` (with two certificates) and `private.key` (and `domain.csr`) and would like to use those on an Apache server (version unknown) for SSL support.

- `+` My website is hosted by a share-hoster (assistance not provided).
- `+` I have FTP access to the webspace.
- `+` I can give commands like `chmod` via FTP interface (but not e.g. `ls -l`).
- `+` I can use things like `.htaccess`.
- `-` I cannot receive mails sent to my (sub)domain name.
- `-` I cannot execute CGI/Phyton scripts in my webspace.
- `-` There is no special website of the share-hoster to mange the site, especially no possibility to input my certificate credentials.
- `-` I do not have SSH or any other console access.
- `-` I do not have access to the configuration files of the webserver (but access to local ones like `.htaccess`).

Is there a possibility to install the SSL certificates?

Comment: Contact your share-hoster and ask them for assistance.

Comment: @Tom: I edited my question: there is no assistance provided - just hosting. "Get another hoster" might be a valid solution to the problem, but just assume a) I do not want to/cannot change the hoster easily  and b) I want to know how to technically solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your list of requirements, your question is effectively a duplicate of the SO question: [How to setup ssl using only .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38054124/4635198)

Unfortunately the answer is you cannot, because as you wrote:

> I do not have access to the configuration files of the webserver (but access to local ones like .htaccess).

Technically, how you would do this in apache is you would edit the server configuration file. Add to the VirtualHost section, the SSL certificate and key information. A simple example:

```
<VirtualHost <IPADDRESS>:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/directory

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile      /path/to/relevant/domain.crt
  SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/relevant/chain.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/relevant/private.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Since your shared hosting does not allow you to edit this file, and it seems they will not 'support you' by editing the file on your behalf, your path forward is blocked.